# JavaEE + Jax RS + WebApp: configure url-pattern for default servlet?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have a JAX-RS service that works fine without a web.xml descriptor (via @ApplicationPath("/") annotation). However, when I add an empty web.xml descriptor in order to serve static files from the same war, I get a "Forbidden" status from the http server for the JAX-RS endpoint.

What's the recommended way to mix WebApplications and JAX-RS in the context of JavaEE?

Basically, I want to limit the default servlet to "/assets/*" and deploy JAX-RS to "/*" (exploiting the fact that longer matches have precedence). So configuring the default servlet is the critical part. Is there a JavaEE-compliant way of doing this? Can I reference the default servlet in a JavaEE-compliant way somehow? Or is there a simple servlet implementation I can use?

Comment: Did you mean "...in order to **serve** static files..."?

Comment: What do you mean by default servlet ? Are you saying you want to have all requests that go to /assets/* to hit your own servlet and everything else must hit /* ?

Comment: No, the other way round. But that doesn't matter. It seems there is no JavaEE way to identify the default servlet. Instead one has to use a custom implementation or use the specific app server's class. I finally gave up on it and assigned /assets/* to a REST GET method I implemented myself. JavaEE is pretty incomplete. No file upload standardized, no servlet encoding default settable with standard methods (coming with servlet 4.0)..... and that's only the stuff I found during the first few days of migrating my stuff to JavaEE...